# How do I prevent OS X from joining a particular open network?

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-snow-leopard

There is an open wireless network near my home, and I don't want to join it. Unfortunately, OS X does it automatically, and I have to manually select my own network.

How can I configure AirPort to automatically join my network, and not theirs? The one I'm avoiding is even called Linksys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to System Preferences --> Network, and press "Advanced", under "AirPort" you will find a list of networks entitled "Preferred Networks." You can simply remove a network from this list and it will no longer be automatically connected to.

If you still want to connect to this network automatically, but want to connect to your network first, simply drag the network you don't want to connect to further down the list, under the one you do want to connect to.

Comment: I've done this a bajillion times, to no effect. Still constantly joins the ubiquitous (in my city) ShawOpen in preference of known closed networks.